# why elasticsearch exact match ignore symbols?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and this has got me stuck for hours. basically I want to search for the following:

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
          "heading":"Retweet - Barbara Keeley (Labour MP)"
      } 
   }
}
```

And it gives me exactly what I want, however if I change the the phrase to the following:

"heading":"Retweet - Barbara Keeley (Labour MP"

See, I remove the bracket in the end, it still give me the same result, it looks like when running a search, it will ignore special characters like ")", or "@" and only search for letters.

So please advise if I want to search for exactly what entered, how do I do this? like if I add any special character or remove any, it should not give me any result.

The mapping info is:

```
{
  politicaldataheading: {
    mappings: {
      politicaldata: {
        properties: {
          date: {
            type: "date",
            format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          heading: {
            type: "string"
          },
          id: {
            type: "long"
          },
          time: {
            type: "date",
            format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the mapping of heading.

Comment: Title says "exact match" but your JSON mentions "phrase". You're probably triggering a full-text search.

Comment: You need `heading` to be `"heading": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }` for that query to work. The whole idea here is about analyzing the text by ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Comment: thanks @Andrei Stefan  I find it bit hard to understand. what shall I do from here?

Comment: To be honest, I could give you the complete set of steps to perform, but would probably be better for you if you do a bit of reading regarding Elasticsearch. It will help you in the long run. Using analyzers and understanding the basic query types and how ES is working is essential for anyone using Elasticsearch.